# Need to Run a vbscipt via Batch file in Silent mode

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I know this is a duplicate. But I am stuck and not able to understand those properly.

The first vbs file:

```
Msgbox "Success"
```

The Bat File:

```
@echo off
Start "C:\Success.vbs" %*
```

I need to run the bat file in silent mode. Could anyone explain me how i can do that.

Comment: What do you mean by silent mode?

Comment: No CMD window should pop up. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another VBS file as a wrapper:

```
Dim Shell
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "C:\Whatever.bat", 0
```

Now run this VBS file, your batch will be executed without showing a "blackboard".

Answer (score 0):

Change you batch file to this

If you want to use 32-bit,

```
@echo off
@%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c call cscript "C:\Success.vbs"
```

Else,

```
@echo off
cscript "C:\Success.vbs"
```

This will hide additional cmd window, but it won't hide the bat file cmd window.